# If I merge 2 WordPress sites will posts duplicate if same on both

Tags: wordpress, import

I have two WordPress sites which cover similar content and on occasion, have a crossover.

I want to do everything on one site now to make it easier to manage and focus but am worried if I import the posts (using WordPress importer) from Site B to Site A (and 301 old domain) that the posts that are the same would duplicate or would it pick up duplicates and skip them.

Posts would have same title/path

There isn't a massive amount and could potentially manually remove them first but importing as is would be the easiest option.

Anyone have any experience of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you following steps

- import all post first
- after using **SQL query** to find the duplicate post and delete.how to delete post read [this article](http://wpkrauts.com/2013/find-and-delete-duplicate-posts-in-wordpress/).

**Note**: I recommend that you back up your database before doing anything.